# Get first and last folder from an url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In a Chrome extension i have a variable, which equals current tab's url, like `currentUrl = tabs[0].url;`. It gets an url like `http://www.example.com/folder-1/folder-2/folder-3/index.html`.

I want to get `/folder/-1` and `/folder-3/` from this url.

Tried `currentPath = currentUrl.substring(0, currentUrl.lastIndexOf("/"));`, but on this way i get only the whole path (`http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3`)

Comment: `http://www.example.com/folder-1/folder-2/folder-3/index.html`.split('/')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const arr = "http://www.example.com/folder-1/folder-2/folder-3/index.html".split("/");
```

Then `arr[3]` would give you folder-1
and `arr[arr.length - 2]` would give you folder-3

Comment: `const arr = currentUrl.split("/");` is working like expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible way to do that

```
splittedPath = ("http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/index.html").split("/");
folder1 = splittedPath[3];
folderLast = splittedPath[splittedPath.length-2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's test some more cases:

```js
function getFirstAndLastFrom( URL ){

  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = URL;
  let pathname = a.pathname.split("/");
  pathname.shift();  // Filter out first entry
  pathname.pop();    // Filter out last entry
  const first = pathname.length > 0 ? pathname[0] : null; // Do we have a first element?
  const last = pathname.length > 1 ? pathname[pathname.length-1] : null; // Do we have a last element?
  return { first, last };

}
```

```js
const URL1 = "http://www.example.com/folder-1/folder-2/folder-3/index.html";
const URL2 = "http://example.com/folder-1/folder-2/folder-3/";
const URL3 = "http://www.example.com";
const URL4 = "http://subdomain.example.com/folder-1/folder-2/image.jpg";
const URL5 = "http://www.example.com/folder-1/image.jpg";
const URL6 = "http://www.google.com/";

{
  // Test case #1
  let { first, last } = getFirstAndLastFrom( URL1 );
  console.log( URL1, first, last );
}

{
  // Test case #2
 let { first, last } = getFirstAndLastFrom( URL2 );
  console.log( URL2, first, last );
}

{
  // Test case #3
  let { first, last } = getFirstAndLastFrom( URL3 );
  console.log( URL3, first, last );
}

{
  // Test case #4
  let { first, last } = getFirstAndLastFrom( URL4 );
  console.log( URL4, first, last );
}

{
  // Test case #5
  let { first, last } = getFirstAndLastFrom( URL5 );
  console.log( URL5, first, last );
}

{
  // Test case #6
  let { first, last } = getFirstAndLastFrom( URL6 );
  console.log( URL6, first, last );
}
```